# jQuery animation inside recursive function very slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a small animation of an arrow bouncing horizontaly over three car pictures. The arrow starts with 200ms per bounce and the time increases by 200ms each turn, until it stops on 7th turn on car #3.

It works on Chrome and Firefox almost smoothly. On Safari 7 it starts fast and after two laps it becomes very slow and skips a lot of frames.

The Javascript code is the following:

```
var fwd = true;
var cnt = 6;
var time = 200;

function play(){
    var tgt = fwd ? '310px' : '10px';

    $('#arrow').animate({left: tgt}, time, function() {
        if (cnt > 0){
            cnt--;
            fwd = !fwd;
            time += 200;
            play();
        } else {
            finalTarget();
        }
    });

}

function finalTarget (){
    $('#arrow').animate({left: '230px'}, 466, function(){
        $('#car3').hide(0).show('pulsate', {times: 3}, 600, function(){
            $('#car1, #car2').fadeTo('slow', 0.3);
        });
    });
}
```

The code is also on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MkeeE/1/

What's the problem with this code?

Am I not supposed to call the "play" function inside the callback function?

**EDIT**:
As @jfriend00 pointed on comments, there's no recursion on this code. "By the time the animation completion function is called and `play()` is called again, the original invocation of `play()` has long since completed."

Comment: Your code requires a lot of repainting. If you want a smooth animation, use CSS keyframes...

Comment: dumb it down. is this just as choppy? http://jsfiddle.net/MkeeE/2/

Comment: @KevinB no. This runs smoothly on safari.

Comment: next would be to add the rest into it: http://jsfiddle.net/MkeeE/4/ (to me, they both look kinda choppy even in chrome)

Comment: This one is very choppy.

Comment: Try `setTimeout(play, 0)` instead. Not sure if it will make a difference.

Comment: @enyce12 Could you please give some example on how to implement it using CSS keyframes? I've been told that it is better than .animation using position: absolute.

Comment: @jon no difference with `setTimeout(play, 0)`

Comment: @Jon - the animation completion function (which is where successive calls to `play()` originate from) is itself already called from a timer so changing to `setTimeout(play, 0)` will solve nothing and will add a 15ms or so delay.

Comment: The problem was just with Safari. After a reboot, I can't reproduce the choppy animation anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The typical method of doing a 'looping' animation style is to alternate animate functions in the call back.

I modified the fiddle you provided: http://jsfiddle.net/Culyx/fLz5U/4/

**Jquery:**

```
cnt = 6;

var arrowSpeed = 400;
bounceLeft = function(){
        $("#arrow").animate({left: "+=380px"},{duration:arrowSpeed, complete: bounceRight});
    }
    bounceRight = function(){
        cnt--;
        if(cnt>0){
            $("#arrow").animate({left: "-=380px"},{duration:arrowSpeed, complete: bounceLeft});}else{
            finalTarget();
            }
    }
bounceLeft();


function finalTarget (){
    $('#arrow').animate({left: '230px'}, 466, function(){
        $('#car3').hide(0).show('pulsate', {times: 3}, 600, function(){
            $('#car1, #car2').fadeTo('slow', 0.3);
        });
    });
}
```

The animation is the same but I think i misjudged the animation width; Also switched it to on Document.Ready can easily be switched back to function with a button.

Comment: Ok, this implementation is nicer mine, but I'm also using the callback on my example and you are also using recursion on yours, but in two steps. The problem is that the result is the same on Safari.

Comment: Call back is weird in that sense, I do call another function at each completion but those are distinct functions your call back is calling a function that wraps the animate and call; In essence i would guess that [Play() starts -> Animate() starts -> Animate() finishes -> callback -> Play() starts] and as such you never really "finish" a Play() call hence the overhead.

Comment: The OP's code is NOT recursive.  By the time the animation completion function is called and `play()` is called again, the original invocation of `play()` has long since completed.  The successive invocation of `play()` is being called from a jQuery timer.  This is NOT recursive.  It appears recursive by reading the code, but because the completion function is asynchronous and occurs sometime later AFTER the original invocation of `play()` finishes, this is not recursion and calling itself in this way does not cause any accumulation of resources in any way.

Comment: @jfriend00 is correct. I never though this way, but neither my code nor @Culyx's code are recursive. The `play` function is called after it was finished. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @jfriend00 well explained, still not sure what the differences in performance would be then, edit to my post as well